# Nest cant inject HttpService when it is used in the separate library

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a REST API project that includes a Nest library to register interceptors in the AxiosRef of the Nest HttpService, and it is currently functioning as intended by being imported into the providers of the AppModule in the REST API project.

This is the code of the library that works when in the same repository as the API

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios'

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorsService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {
    this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      console.log('Interceptor is running...')
      return config
    })
  }
}
```

This is the AppModule of the API

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { HttpInterceptorsService } from './http-interceptors'; 

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [HttpInterceptorsService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But when I simply move the class that registers the interceptors from the library within the API repository to a new repository built for the library and import the class into the API project, it gives the following error:

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpInterceptorsService (?). Please make sure that the argument HttpService at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.`

This is the AppModule that is encountering the error when using the HttpInterceptorsService imported from the created library.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { HttpInterceptorsService } from 'http-interceptors-lib'; 

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [HttpInterceptorsService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can do the following:

Export HttpService from the library: In your http-interceptors-lib library, you should export the HttpService along with the HttpInterceptorsService class. Modify your http-interceptors-lib as follows:

// http-interceptors-lib.ts

export * from './http-interceptors.service'; // Export your interceptor service
export { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios'; // Export HttpService from NestJS

Import HttpService and HttpInterceptorsService from the library: In your AppModule of the API project, import both HttpService and HttpInterceptorsService from the external library:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { HttpService, HttpInterceptorsService } from 'http-interceptors-lib';

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [HttpService, HttpInterceptorsService], // Add HttpService to the providers
})
export class AppModule {}
```

By exporting HttpService from your library and importing it along with HttpInterceptorsService in your application module, you ensure that Nest can resolve the dependencies correctly.

With these changes, your Nest application should be able to use the HttpInterceptorsService imported from the external library without any dependency resolution issues.`enter code here`

Comment: When I made this change, it presented the following error: `ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.`

Answer (score 0):

```
Check Axios Module Configuration:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.register({
      baseURL: 'https://api.example.com', // Your API base URL
      timeout: 5000, // Timeout value in milliseconds
      // Other Axios configuration options
    }),
  ],
  providers: [], // Your providers
})
export class AppModule {}
Check Dependency Injection:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {
    // ...
  }
}
Avoid injecting AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN directly as it might lead to dependency resolution issues.
Check Import Statements:
Ensure that you are importing HttpService from @nestjs/axios and not from any other` location or external library.
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
```